# View controller is drawing under my navigation bar after popping ttthumbsviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, three20

I'm implementing the TTThumbsViewController from the Three20 project and things are finally starting to take shape.  I push the TTThumbsViewController from the current view controller by just pushing it onto the current stack and animate the transition (common navigation controller push).

My problem is that when I pop the TThumbsViewController view controller, the navigation controller is stuck in a mode where its view controllers are drawn UNDER the navigation bar (which is now translucent).

**Start**

[image]

**Push**

[image]
<sub>(source: [ncsu.edu](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/sbklein/push.PNG))</sub>

**Pop**

[image]
<sub>(source: [ncsu.edu](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/sbklein/pop.PNG))</sub>

Comment: I fixed the problem by forcing the navigation bar to be style BlackOpaque.  The drawing code probably draws point 0,0 under the navigation bar if it is set to translucent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to reconfigure the original style of the status bar, navigation bar & tool bar when your view reappears. You can do this by implementing `viewWillAppear:` in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
  navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
  navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
  navController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, this is also the only way I've been able to get three20 to change the statusbar style while launching the splash screen (or just before the first view shows if you're initially hiding the statusbar during the splash screen).  Thanks for the bread crumbs that got me there

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the view controller you are pushing from does not inherit from TTViewController. You may also need to set the 'navigationBarTintColor' property back to your original color after the view has been popped off the stack; if you have not set a global stylesheet.